Understanding and reporting Cox models with spline terms
I have fit a Cox model with pspline() terms for the continuous covariates. I am trying to have a better understanding of what happens to report my results appropriately. I am using R and the survival package.
Regarding reporting, I have found several suggestions using the rms package. Since I have not used this package, I am looking for alternative using R base. What is the difference between ggplot(Predict(cph(*))) and termplot(coxph(*))? The shape is the same but the values are not, e.g.:
library(survival)
library(rms)

# ggplot(Predict(cph(*)))
dd <- datadist(lung)
options(datadist = "dd")
fit1 <- cph(Surv(time, status) ~ rcs(age, 3) + sex, data = lung)
ggplot(Predict(fit1, age))

# termplot(coxph(*))
fit2 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ rcs(age, 3) + sex, data = lung)
termplot(fit2, term = 1, se = TRUE)



Or using pspline() instead of rcs() (see here and here for interpreting coxph() output with pspline() terms):
(fit3 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ pspline(age) + sex, data = lung))
# Call:
# coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ pspline(age) + sex, data = lung)
# 
#                          coef se(coef)      se2    Chisq   DF      p
# pspline(age), linear  0.01690  0.00903  0.00903  3.50036 1.00 0.0614
# pspline(age), nonlin                             2.94070 3.09 0.4168
# sex                  -0.51821  0.16843  0.16813  9.46671 1.00 0.0021
# 
# Iterations: 4 outer, 11 Newton-Raphson
#      Theta= 0.809 
# Degrees of freedom for terms= 4.1 1.0 
# Likelihood ratio test=17.8  on 5.09 df, p=0.003
# n= 228, number of events= 165 

termplot(fit3, term = 1, se = TRUE)


Anyway, I do not have a clear understanding of what these functions actually do. If I understand correctly, pspline() and rcs() allow non linearity between the covariate and the outcome (e.g. different HR for age = 40 and age = 80).
But what exactly I am looking at when plotting the termplot() of a pspline() term of a Cox model? e.g.

How to interpret the plot? Based on the third plot, can we say that HR = exp(-0.2) for age = 40 and HR = exp(0.6) for age = 80?
Can we interpret the slope of the curve? Without pspline(), the slope of the regression line corresponds to the coefficient of the variable in the full model (code at the end of the post).
Can we report a single, average value?

By the way, depending of authors and functions, the y-axis is labelled differently (e.g. "Partial for age" in termplot(); "log Relative Hazard" in rms:::ggplot.Predict(); or "Relative death rate" in the splines vignette, figure 2, also discussed here), which further confuses me.

fit4 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex, data = lung)
age <- termplot(fit4, term = 1, se = TRUE, plot = FALSE)$age
identical(
  coef(fit4)[[1]],
  (age$y[which.max(age$x)] - age$y[which.min(age$x)]) / (max(age$x) - min(age$x))
)
# [1] TRUE


For the record, a useful reference about splines is Modeling Survival Data: Extending the Cox Model, section 5.5 (see also the introduction, i.e. the first page).

With Cox survival regression models, what you get are estimated log-hazard differences or hazard ratios. Plots like those you show are log-hazard differences from some chosen reference condition.
You'll note that the first two plots have the same shapes and only differ in the alignments on the vertical axis and in the widths of the bands displayed around the point estimates. The difference in vertical-axis alignment comes from different reference condition choices. The age corresponding to a y-axis value of 0 is the reference condition. The plot from ggplot(Predict(fit1, age)) uses an age of approximately 44, based on the default choices made by the rms datadist() and Predict() functions. The plot from termplot(fit2, term = 1, se = TRUE) has an age reference value somewhere in the 60s, probably at the mean of the age values.
The difference in vertical axis labeling comes from termplot() being a very generic function for a wide range of regression models while rms::Predict() takes into account that it's working with a Cox model and thus knows to label that axis as "log Relative Hazard" (emphasis added to harken back to the previous paragraphs). The "Partial" nomenclature in the termplot() output just means that the display is the "partial" association between age and outcome, which means with the other predictors held constant.
The widths of the bands differ a bit between those two plots. rms::Predict() uses 95% confidence limits by default. It turns out that the SE=TRUE argument to termplot() doesn't display dashed lines at 1 standard error away from the point estimates above and below; the internal code for the function leads to the curves being 2 standard errors away. Close, but not the same as for Predict(). In this code excerpt from termplot, note the ff=2 argument:
se.lines <- function(x, iy, i, ff = 2) {
        tt <- ff * terms$se.fit[iy, i]
        lines(x, tms[iy, i] + tt, lty = lty.se, lwd = lwd.se, 
            col = col.se)
        lines(x, tms[iy, i] - tt, lty = lty.se, lwd = lwd.se, 
            col = col.se)
    }

The difference between rcs() (restricted cubic spline) and pspline() (penalized smoothing spline) is outlined on this page, along with several other ways to model nonlinear associations between continuous predictors and outcomes. The rcs() function uses a fixed number of cubic functions that are constrained to meet smoothly at the specified knot locations; the only "penalization" comes from the choice of the number of knots. More knots gives a more flexible fit, but at the risk of overfitting. The pspline() function uses what's usually a larger number of cubic basis functions (by default, 10) but penalizes the coefficients for those basis functions to avoid overfitting. You could probably come close to your (apparently more flexible) pspline() fit by increasing the number of knots you asked for in rcs().
To answer your specific questions:

You must specify the reference condition for a hazard ratio. Reference condition choices can differ among software implementations.

If there's a non-linear association between a continuous predictor and outcome, then there is no single slope. That means:

Reporting a single "average" value can be misleading. Show the whole curve from the full model. Illustrate the results by examining differences between informative, representative situations.



Thank you very much, it is very useful, as usual! Thank you for the clarification regarding the reference for interpretating the plot. So based on e.g. figure 2 of the splines vignette, it is correct to interpret that HR = 20 for age = 90 compared to age = 50? (i.e. the reference set in the code just above the figure; also note that the y-axis is exponentiated)

@Thomas yes, that's how I read that plot along with the associated text.

See also here for interpreting HR from termplot()-like plots.

See also this excellent new paper: Graphical methods to illustrate the nature of the relation between a continuous variable and the outcome when using restricted cubic splines with a Cox proportional hazards model by Peter Austin

@FrankHarrell thanks for the link.

@FrankHarrell Thanks you very much, this article is illuminating!
